# R: How to replace NA in a column within same dataframe where certain columns match?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe 'players' (excerpt below). Whenever column 'match' is NA, I want to replace that NA with a match number from a separate row that has both the same 'Start.Date' and 'Ground'. For example, row 96588 below has 'match' NA but it has the same 'Start.Date' and 'Ground' as row 2. Row 2 has match as '1'. So, as a result of my query I want to populate 'match' in row 96588 as '1' too.

```
              Player            Start.Date        Inns_Bat    Ground     match
2:            NFD Thomson (AUS) 2018-08-09        1           Lord's     1
3:            NFD Thomson (AUS) 2014-12-12        3           Lord's     23
4:            NFD Thomson (AUS) 2018-08-09        1           Eden G     97
96588:        SM Curran (ENG)   2018-08-09        4           Lord's     NA
```

Expected Output:

```
              Player            Start.Date        Inns_Bat    Ground     match
2:            NFD Thomson (AUS) 2018-08-09        1           Lord's     1
3:            NFD Thomson (AUS) 2014-12-12        3           Lord's     23
4:            NFD Thomson (AUS) 2018-08-09        1           Eden G     97
96588:        SM Curran (ENG)   2018-08-09        4           Lord's     1
```

So, 'NA' in row 96588 is replaced by '1' from row 2 because both 'Start.Date' and 'Ground' match in both rows. It is NOT replaced from row 3 or 4 because either 'Start.Date' or 'Ground' does not match with row 96588.

Comment: Can you please format your code properly and use `dput` for your sample data. It also seems you're working with a `data.table` rather than a `data.frame`.

Comment: Hi Mauritz, Is the formatting better now? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. Your original post contained a lot more entries. I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do. Your expected output would help clarify the issue. Perhaps `dplyr::coalesce` does what you're after, see my answer below?

Comment: Hi Mauritz, I have tried to elaborate better by including some more rows and an expected output. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Ok (I think) I understand. I've updated my answer below, please take a look.

Comment: It doesn't work. "Error in rowid_to_column(., "row") : 
  could not find function "rowid_to_column". Also, I hope you understand the table has hundreds of thousands of columns - a few thousands of them have match 'NA' and all others have a match number. I want a generic solution to replace all the 'NA' matches by matching Start.Date and Ground.

Comment: You need to `library(tidyverse)` (hence "a `tidyverse` option" in my post). I've made an edit to make this explicit. *"Also, I hope you understand the table"* No need to "hope" for anything. You need to understand that I go by what little information you provide;-)

Comment: Still no luck - all the NA matches are still NA (although I can see other rows with match number populated have same Start.Date and Ground).

Comment: You need to provide **representative & minimal sample data**; please understand that statements such as "Still no luck" **don't provide any insight** into what's going on. My answer below works for the sample data you give. I'm afraid that's all I can say at this point.

Comment: My mistake. I think your solution works for the data. But it seems like the answer is a different type of object. It looks different (It says 'a tibble' whereas previously it didn't); and simple queries like "players[players$match==1]" don't work after applying this.

Comment: A `tibble` is very similar to a `data.frame`; to convert back to a `data.frame` just add `%>% as.data.frame()` to the `dplyr` chain.

Comment: Ok I converted to dataframe. But after that when I say "temp[temp$match==1]" it says "Error in `[.data.frame`(temp, temp$match == 1) : 
  undefined columns selected" Is this expected? The same query used to work before this operation.

Comment: I cannot confirm any of these issues. I've just checked and indexing works just fine with the `tibble`s, see my update below. There's no need to `as.data.frame()`. Did you perhaps forget to store the chain in a new object?

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Just a small follow-up - earlier "df[df$match==1]" used to yield a result. But now, I need to put an extra comma to get the same result i.e. "df.new[df.new$match==1,]". Why do I need an extra comma now? Is it possible to revert to the previous format which didn't need this extra comma? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because `df.new` is now a `tibble` and not a `data.frame`. You can [index `data.frame`s](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html) either as `list`s with a single vector index, or like a matrix with a comma-separated row and column vector index. `tibble`s on the other hand are always indexed like a matrix, e.g. `df[row_idx, col_idx]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidvyerse)
df.new <- df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    group_by(Start.Date, Ground) %>%
    fill(match) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(row) %>%
    select(-row)
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  Player            Start.Date Inns_Bat Ground match
#  <fct>             <fct>         <int> <fct>  <int>
#1 NFD Thomson (AUS) 2018-08-09        1 Lord's     1
#2 NFD Thomson (AUS) 2014-12-12        3 Lord's    23
#3 NFD Thomson (AUS) 2018-08-09        1 Eden G    97
#4 SM Curran (ENG)   2018-08-09        4 Lord's     1


df.new[df.new$match == 1, ]
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Player            Start.Date Inns_Bat Ground match
#  <fct>             <fct>         <int> <fct>  <int>
#1 NFD Thomson (AUS) 2018-08-09        1 Lord's     1
#2 SM Curran (ENG)   2018-08-09        4 Lord's     1
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Player            Start.Date        Inns_Bat    Ground     match
'NFD Thomson (AUS)' 2018-08-09        1           'Lord\\'s'     1
'NFD Thomson (AUS)' 2014-12-12        3           'Lord\\'s'     23
'NFD Thomson (AUS)' 2018-08-09        1           'Eden G'     97
'SM Curran (ENG)'   2018-08-09        4           'Lord\\'s'     NA", header = T)
```

Comment: @user7483219 If this answers your question please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.